# Question regarding basic counting

Tags: combinatorics

I was doing some questions regarding basic counting and couldn't solve them. I was wondering if someone could help me out. My lecturer didn't teach this part properly so I have no idea how to get started.

The question is:

> Consider the word SASSAFRAS
>
> 1. How many distinct words can be made by using all letters of the word?
> 2. How many of these words have no letter in the same place as in the original word?
> 3. How many distinct words can be made from the letters of this word, where all letters in the word must be different?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you share your thoughts on these problems, and explain what you've tried and what's giving you difficulty?

Comment: I am very confused as to what I have to do to solve these problems? My lecturer didn't teach me properly so I have no idea how to solve them

Comment: @user123456 SOFTENG 211???

Answer (score 3):

I’ll discuss the first problem in detail and give some pointers for the other two.

If all $9$ letters of the word SASSAFRAS were distinct, there would be $9!$ permutations of those $9$ letters, i.e., $9!=362,880$ distinct words that could be made using all $9$ of them. However, $4$ of the $9$ are S, and $3$ are A. Once we decide which $4$ positions in the word are to contain the S’s, it doesn’t matter which of the $4!$ permutations of those $4$ S’s we use: they all yield the same word. All that matters is which $4$ positions contain the S’s. There are $\binom94$ ways to choose $4$ positions for the S’s. That leaves $9-4=5$ positions, and there are $\binom53$ ways to choose $3$ of them for the A’s. That leaves only $2$ positions unfilled; there are $\binom21$ ways to pick one of them for the F, and the remaining one must of course get the R. Thus, there are

$$\binom94\binom52\binom21=\frac{9!}{4!5!}\cdot\frac{5!}{3!2!}\cdot\frac{2!}{1!1!}=\frac{9!}{4!3!1!1!}$$

different ways to arrange the letters of SASSAFRAS. You may notice that the $4,3,1$, and $1$ of the factorials in the denominator correspond exactly to the numbers of S’s, A’s, F’s, and R’s that we have available. That’s not an accident, as you can see if you trace through the argument thinking of what might happen in general. There’s another way to see it, as well. Suppose that we temporarily label the S’s, S<sub>1</sub>, S<sub>2</sub>, S<sub>3</sub>, and S<sub>4</sub>, and similarly label the individual A’s. Then we can think of SASSAFRAS as containing $9$ different letters, and they can be arranged in $9!$ different ways. Now pick one of those arrangements, and match it up with all of the other arrangmenents that have the S’s and A’s in the same positions. The $4$ S’s can appear in their same positions in $4!$ different permutations, and the $3$ A’s can appear in their same positions in $3!$ different permutations, so there are altogether $4!\cdot3!$ different words that would look the same if we hadn’t labelled the multiple letters. Thus, each distinguishable word is actually counted $4!\cdot3!$ times in the crude estimate of $9!$, and we have to divide $9!$ by $4!\cdot3!$ to get rid of this over-counting.

The word SASSAFRAS has only $4$ different letters, A, F, R, and S, so in the third problem you need only consider words of lengths $1,2,3$, and $4$. Count separately the words of these lengths that don’t repeat any letters. Obviously there are just $4$ of length $1$, and it’s pretty basic that there are $4!=24$ of length $4$. In building a $2$-letter word without repetition you have $4$ choices for the first letter, and once it’s chosen you have $3$ choices for the second letter; how should you combine those numbers to get the number of $2$-letter words without a repeated letter? What does the same idea give you for the number of $3$-letter words without repetition?

The second problem is conceptually the messiest. I’d approach it by first noticing that the $4$ S’s have to go into $4$ of the $5$ positions not currently occupied by S’s; in how many ways can you choose $4$ of those $5$ positions? Now split it into two cases depending on whether the fifth non-S position, the one that you **didn’t** fill with an S, originally had an A in it or not. If it had an A, you must fill it with either the F or the R, and you then have $3$ A’s and one odd letter to distribute in the $4$ original S positions; counting the number of ways to do that is a problem of the same type as the first problem. If it had the F or the R, you must distinguish two subcases: you can fill it with the other single letter, in which case again you’re distributing $3$ A’s and one odd letter amongst the $4$ original S positions; or you can fill it with an A, in which case you’re distributing $2$ A’s, the F, and the R amongst those $4$ positions.

**Added:** For the second problem we must distribute the $4$ S’s amongst the $5$ other positions. There are $5$ ways to choose which of the $5$ we don’t use; in $3$ of those cases it’s an old A position, in one it’s the old F position, and in one it’s the old R position.

1. Suppose that we leave one of the old A slots unused; that means that we’ve filled the old F and R slots and $2$ of the old A slots with S’s, and we now have to distribute AAAFR amongst the $4$ old S slots and the open A slot. We have to put the F or the R into the open A slot. No matter which of the $2$ we use, the other must go into one of old S slots, as must the $3$ A’s. It’s a $2$-way choice between the F and the R to fill the open A slot, and then it’s a $4$-way choice to decide into which old S slot the other single letter goes, so there are $2\cdot4=8$ words in this case. However, there are $3$ old A slots, so there are $3$ instances of this case, for a total of $3\cdot8=24$ words.
2. Suppose that we leave the old F slot unused. That means that we’ve filled all $3$ of the old A slots and the R slot with the $4$ S’s, leaving the $4$ old S slots and the old F slot to be filled with AAAFR. There are two subcases.

   - If we put the R into the old F slot, we end up filling the old S slots with AAAF. The only choice is where to put the F, and it can be made in $4$ ways, so there are $4$ words in this subcase.
   - If we put an A into the old F slot, we end up filling the $4$ old S slots with AAFR. There are $4$ ways to choose one of them for the F; once that’s done, there are $3$ ways to choose one of the remaining slots for the R, and the $2$ A’s then go into the last two slots. Thus, there are $4\cdot 3$ words in this subcase, and Case (2) ends up accounting for $4+12=16$ words.
3. Suppose that we leave the old R slot unused. The analysis is then exactly like that of Case (2), except that F and R are interchanged, so we get another $16$ words.

The grand total is therefore $24+16+16=56$ words that have no letter in its original position.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer question 1. Can you give me a hint as to how I can start question (2) and (3)

Comment: @user123456: You’re welcome. I’ve added some advice for the third question; the second one is quite messy, and I’m still thinking about the best way to approach it.

Comment: @user123456: And I’ve now added some suggestions for the second question as well.

Comment: thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @user123456: You’re very welcome.

Comment: so for question (3) is the answer 64 because for 4 letter there is 24, 3 letter is 24 and 2 letter is 12 and 1 letter is 4 so the the total number of words is 64

Comment: @user123456: That’s what I get.

Comment: would the answer for (2) be 5C4*6C3*8C1*8C1 = 6400

Comment: @user123456: No, you won’t get it by a simple multiplication: there are cases that have to be counted separately and then added together. For instance, suppose that you’ve put the $4$ S’s into the positions originally occupied by the $3$ A’s and the F. Then you can either put the F into the old R slot and distribute the $3$ A’s and the F in the old S slots, or you can put an A into the old R slot and distribute $2$ A’s, the F, and the R in the old S slots. There are $4$ ways to do the first of these and $\frac{4!}{2!1!1!}=12$ ways to do the second, ...

Comment: ... so there are $4+12=16$ words that have the $4$ S’s in the old A and F slots (and no letter in its original position).

Comment: I have tried many different ways but I can't seem to figure out the answer. Can you please give me the answer and explain why?

Comment: @user123456: It really is a fairly messy problem, unless I’m missing something clever. It will take me a few minutes to write up.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help so far.

Comment: @user123456: You’re welcome. See if you can work through what I’ve added; it may take a little while, but it’s all there.